# Adding element to Java array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I add an element to an array while expanding the length of the array by one unit without using `ArrayList`? I'm a student, and it's forbidden for the assignment.

I have written a method that does it (sort of). It increments the array length every time its called but it only saves the last input parameter tot the very last element (every other element is made null when I create the new array with new length). The method is called in my constructor that makes an instance of an object from every line scanned in a text file, and I am supposed to add this line to an instance array.

Comment: Show us the code you've written.

Comment: Can you "cheat" by [reading how Java does it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java/)?

Comment: Try to write some code... Then show them to us. We will help later on. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can only create a new array which is longer than the old one. Other references of your program, already having a reference to the old array, are not affected and keep the old sized array.